How to download a file from team via drag-and-drop
when I drag-and-drop a file from a channel in teams I get the following information in my c# program (after some decoding):
{
  "itemKeys": [
    [
      "spItem_999",
      "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SomeTeamsChanel",
      "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SomeTeamsChanel/shared documents",
      "42",
      ""
    ],
    [
      "spItem_999",
      "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SomeTeamsChanel",
      "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SomeTeamsChanel/shared documents",
      "24",
      ""
    ]
  ]
}

Is it possible to create urls with this information to download the files?
Edit (after some research):
When I take the above information to form an URL like this:
"https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SomeTeamsChanel/shared documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?view=7&q=ListItemId=24"
and enter the URL in the browser, I came to a page where the single file is listed.
But when I download the file via browser I need an URL like this:
"https://somecompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SomeTeamsChanel/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=1fe147af%2D4a1d%2D4e93%2Db440%2D823fd54fb009"
Questions:

How I get the UniqueId for file to download from its ListItemId?
Is it always "view=7" (when I want to list the file, first link)?
Is it always "_layouts/15" (when I want to download the file, second link)?)
The logged in user and executor of my program have the right to download the file via browser, how do i have to authorize my application so that it can also download the file?

Thanks in advance
